# Getting text response of the assistant's conversation?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

With the `ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED` event, the user's query is obtained in text. But how do you get a text response of the Assistant's reply ?
Is there any text field in `ON_RESPONDING_FINISHED` event. I want to display the assistant's reply, how is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do this as of the [Google Assistant Service developer preview v1alpha2](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/release-notes#february_20th_2018).

See this similar StackOverflow question for more context: [How to receive answer from Google Assistant as a String, not as an audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123641/how-to-receive-answer-from-google-assistant-as-a-string-not-as-an-audio-stream)

Update 4/18/18: You might want to check out [supplemental_display_text](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2#dialogstateout). It's not a transcription of the audio, but works pretty well in many cases.